# Get value from another tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm currently having a problem getting value from another tab page in windows form using c#. I have tabPage1 and tabPage 2 inside tabControl. I want to use the value I have saved in tabpage1 for another calculation in tabPage 2 but I can't find a way to do this. Here is an example of what i want for further understanding my question. Please anyone help me fix this, thank you.

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            double age = Convert.ToDouble(richTextBox1.Text);
 }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {          double a=0;
            for (int i=1,i<age,i++)
        {
            a=a+i;
        }
 }
```

P.s. button1 is in tabPage1 and button2 is in tabPage 2

Comment: You declared `age` local to the scope of `button1_Click_1` so it can't be seen from outside of that block.  Just use that line in the `button2_Click` method.  Do prefer `int.TryParse` to handle bad input that can't convert into numbers.

Comment: "Just use that line in the button2_Click method"

I'm sorry, I don't get this

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know what "method" means before. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an issue with variable scoping. In your `button2_Click` method you are probably getting an error about `age` not being declared.

There are a few options:

1. Get the value of age in your `button2_Click` method again.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       double a = 0;
       double age = Convert.ToDouble(richTextBox1.Text); // Get value again locally.
       for (int i = 1; i < age; i++)
       {
           a += 1;
       }
}
```

This will mean that `age` is available within the scope of `button2_Click`.

2. Store it in a property on the form, making it available to all your methods in that Form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int Age { get; set; } // Property that stores age in the class.

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Age = Convert.ToDouble(richTextBox1.Text); // Store in property not local var
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double a = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < Age; i++) // Loop to property value not local var.
        {
            a += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Which option you choose will depend on your use case (e.g. if pressing button 1 is necessary before pressing button 2, then you will want to go with option 2; but if you could just press button 2 without first pressing button 1 then option 1 would work).

Please note that, in your `for` loop you have used commas, where you need to use semicolons, my example above correct this.

In addition, as @LarsTech has mentioned, you need to use `int.TryParse` ideally, as the value in your textbox may not be a number.

Comment: Ah... I get it now. I'm sorry, I'm new to c# so I didn't know what "method" means. Thank you so much for the detail explanation.